# i want select city from cites table and create View in stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

my stored procedure :

```
USE [maskanjo.com_travelenterDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPSelectCites]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @cityName  nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
--------------------------Select---------------------

CREATE VIEW CUSTOMERS_VIEW AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[City] where [NameFA] LIKE cityName+'%'

-----------------------------------------------------
END
```

i want select city from cites table and create View 
have error 
Error :
Incorrect syntax:'CREATE VIEW' Must be only statement in the batch

Comment: why do you need to create view in a stored procedure ?

Comment: You cannot CREATE VIEW in a stored procedure unless you use exec/spexecutesql - the question really is *why* do you want to create a view in a stored procedure?

Comment: With the logic as expressed, you could only call the stored procedure once.  Why would you want to write a stored procedure that can only be called once?  (One the view is created a subsequent attempt to create it will result in an error.)

Comment: why not just use a view?

Comment: Why not create a CTE instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you what the problem is. Try executing the query using the "Exec" command:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'CREATE VIEW CUSTOMERS_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM [dbo].[City] 
where [NameFA] LIKE ''' + cityName + '%'''
exec (@sql)
```